A rare used Chinese character becomes a junk (?) character
A rare used Chinese character becomes a junk (?) character after being processed.
Here is my test code:
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String a1 = "";
    System.out.println(a1 + ".charAt(0)=" + (a1.charAt(0) + 0));
    StringBuffer a = new StringBuffer();
    a.append("a=C0000002006人力資源處").append(a1.charAt(0));
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
    out.println(a);
    System.out.println(a.toString());
    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
    b.append("b=C0000002006人力資源處").append(a1.substring(0,1));
    out.println(b);
    System.out.println(b.toString());
}

The output is
.charAt(0)=55364
a=C0000002006人力資源處?
a=C0000002006人力資源處?
b=C0000002006人力資源處?
b=C0000002006人力資源處?

Is it a bug ?
How to fix it ?

Try instead StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();a.append("a=C0000002006人力資源處").appendCodePoint(a1.codePointAt(0)); Things have moved on: 1 characters doesn't necessarily equal 1 char - (inspect a1.length()) and you should be using codepoints and StringBuilder

that is why it is recommended to consider using code points (int) instead of char

By the way, you should probably use StringBuilder, not its legacy brother StringBuffer.

@Zabuzard ^____

@Zabuzard StringBuffer is not legacy.  StringBuffer is thread-safe, while StringBuilder is not. StringBuilder may be a little bit faster, and should be preferred where you know thread-safety is not an issue.

Yeah, I am aware. Thing is that in practice, even if you need thread-safety, its usually better to use StringBuilder and put the thread-safety yourself at the actual place where you need it - not on the builder itself. There are a few idiomatic SO discussion on this topic - the class is effectively legacy (hence I went for italic) - perhaps its the wrong choice of words, but you can avoid it.

tl;dr

Avoid char.
Use code points.
Just concatenate; don’t over complicate it.
No need for PrintStream.

"a=C0000002006人力資源處" + ""

See this code run at Ideone.com.
Avoid char
Answer by Jon Skeet is correct.
Let me state the situation more simply: The char type has been essentially broken since Java 2, legacy since Java 5.
As a 16-bit value, char is physically incapable of representing most of the 154,998 characters defined in Unicode.

Do not use char.
Do not call String.length nor similar methods.

Code point
Instead, use code points, numbers ranging from 0 to 1,114,111.
You will find “codePoint” related methods on several classes such as Character, String, and StringBuilder.
IntStream is useful with code points. String#codePoints returns an IntStream of code points.
String a1 = "";
a1.codePoints().forEach( System.out :: println );


136060

We find that the codepoint for your single character is 136,060 rather than the 55,364 returned by your code.
136,060 decimal is 2137C hexadecimal. See that character on Unicode 16 chart, CJK Unified Ideographs Extension B.
No need to involve PrintStream.
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer( "a=C0000002006人力資源處" ) ;
String a1 = "";
buffer.append( a1 ) ;

Dump to console.
System.out.println( buffer.toString() ) ;

See this code run at Ideone.

a=C0000002006人力資源處

Alternatively, you get the same result by appending the code point.
new StringBuffer( "a=C0000002006人力資源處" ).appendCodePoint( 136_060 )


 is represented in Unicode as U+2137C. It's not in the Basic Multilingual Plane of characters that can each be represented in a UTF-16 code unit.
By appending a1.charAt(0) and a1.substring(0, 1) you're assuming that those each result in a complete character - they don't. They result in the first half of the surrogate pair of UTF-16 code units that combine to represent the single Unicode code point of U+2137C.
If you print a1.length() I'd expect it to be 2, and if you append a1 instead of just the first UTF-16 code unit of a1, I'd expect that to work fine.
Basically, you need to understand that a String is a sequence of UTF-16 code units, not a sequence of Unicode characters, and then avoid assuming that each Unicode character can be represented in a single UTF-16 code unit.
